# Using sidebarLayout + reactive in R Shiny document chunk

Tags: r, shiny

I have an Rmd file with shiny enabled so that I can use shiny widgets and R reactive framework within the document.

I'm trying to setup a set of `selectInput` widgets so that the values in one widget depends on the preceding widgets' selection. Something similar to [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateCheckboxGroupInput.html).

But in my case I don't use ui and server function seperately and pass them to `shinyApp()` function. I use `sidebarLayout()` to which I pass the `sidebarPanel` controls argument (set of widgets) and the `mainPanel` argument which is a shiny output function.

Essentially here is how my chunk looks like:

```
all_choices <- c("A", "B", "C")

controls <- sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("input1", label = "Input 1:", choices = all_choices),
  selectInput("input2", label = "Input 2:", choices = all_choices)
)

plotOutput <- renderPlot({
  plot(1:10)
})

sidebarLayout(position = "left", controls, mainPanel(plotOutput))
```

In this chunk, I want to remove the selection from "Input 1" in the choices in "Input 2".

I do understand that I have to use the `observe` function to do achieve this, but not sure where to place it as my chunk doesn't have the `server()` function.

Any help would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it anywhere. It doesn't matter.

Though it looks like it doesn't have the UI and Server part. But it's still the same process in the backend.

```
all_choices <- c("A", "B", "C")

controls <- sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("input1", label = "Input 1:", choices = all_choices),
  selectInput("input2", label = "Input 2:", choices = all_choices)
)

plotOutput <- renderPlot({
  plot(1:10)
})

observe({
  choices1 <- setdiff(all_choices,input$input2)
  updateSelectInput(
    session = session,
    inputId = "input1",
    choices = choices1
  )
})


sidebarLayout(position = "left", controls, mainPanel(plotOutput))
```